# Scala - How to create a label / button that shows more options when clicked

Tags: swing, scala

I'm trying to create a Scala button/label that has more options (such as the menu item options) when clicked.

At the moment I have;

```
val expandableLabel = new Label {
  icon = new ImageIcon("myimage.png")
  listenTo(this)
  reactions += {
    case e: MouseClicked => println("Hey, stop clicking. It tickles.")
  }
}
```

But what I really want is to be able to click on the image and see a list of options (such as checkbox options). Is this possible in Scala?

**Edit:** I believe this can be done with CSS, but what I want to know is if it is possible in purely Scala.

Comment: What UI library are you using? What environment are you developing in?

Comment: I'm simply using the standard library Scala. Working in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a popup-menu:

```
import scala.swing._

val pop = new PopupMenu {
  contents += new MenuItem(Action("Foo")(println("Clicked Foo")))
  contents += new MenuItem(Action("Bar")(println("Clicked Bar")))
}

new Frame {
  contents = new Label("Click me") {
    border = Swing.EmptyBorder(4)
    listenTo(mouse.clicks)
    reactions += {
      case _: event.MouseClicked => 
        pop.show(this, 0, 0)
    }
  }
  pack()
  centerOnScreen()
  open()
}
```

(Note: `PopupMenu` has been added to Scala 2.11; before you would have to use a third party wrapper, such as the one in [ScalaSwingContrib](https://github.com/benhutchison/ScalaSwingContrib)).

---

Otherwise, you might just open a second window, or a dialog:

```
val cb1 = new CheckBox("Foo")
val cb2 = new CheckBox("Bar")

val message = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
  contents += cb1
  contents += cb2
}

val res = Dialog.showConfirmation(message = message.peer, 
                                  optionType = Dialog.Options.OkCancel)
val info = if (res == Dialog.Result.Yes)
  s"Foo? ${cb1.selected}; Bar? ${cb2.selected}"
else
  "Cancelled"
println(info)
```

---

Dynamically changing the contents of a Swing container is a bit more annoying. You will have to add and remove stuff from the container's contents, then revalidate it:

```
var expanded = false
val cb = new CheckBox("Foo")

new Frame { frame =>
  contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) { box =>
    contents += new Button("Expand") {
      preferredSize = preferredSize // so it doesn't change with the label
      listenTo(this)
      reactions += {
        case event.ButtonClicked(_) => 
          expanded = !expanded
          if (expanded) {
            text = "Hide"
            box.contents += cb
          } else {
            text = "Expand"
            box.contents.remove(1)
          }
          box.revalidate()
          frame.pack()
      }
    }
  }
  pack()
  centerOnScreen()
  open()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this, and it looks promising.